# exclude only 1 row based on condition in oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

one table has below value

```
|CIF |FACNO |FAC_NAME  |<br>
|1234|234   | ABCD     |<br>
|1234|235   | xyz      |<br>
|1244|345   | ABCD     |<br>
|1244|346   | ABCDE    |<br>
|1278|238   | xyz      |<br>
```

Sorry, not able to formart data into table 
if for same CIF , if FAC_NAME=ABCD and fac_name=XYz then exclude only "xyz" row for that specific CIF and display rest

Answer (score 1):

This one returns the desired result (at least, I think so), but is **so clumsy** that I'm pretty much sure that someone else will post a far better option. Anyway, here you go.

INTER is used to distinguish 'abcd' and 'xyz' from other FAC_NAME values (that's what HM represents). It is then used to check whether certain CIF contains both of them (i.e. sum of HM = 1 - 1 = 0) and - if that's the case - it doesn't return a row that contains FAC_NAME = 'xyz'.

```
SQL> with test (cif, facno, fac_name) as
  2    (select 1234, 234, 'abcd'  from dual union
  3     select 1234, 235, 'xyz'   from dual union
  4     select 1234, 236, 'ooo'   from dual union
  5     select 1244, 345, 'abcd'  from dual union
  6     select 1244, 346, 'abcde' from dual union
  7     select 1278, 238, 'xyz'   from dual
  8    ),
  9  inter as
 10    (select cif, facno, fac_name,
 11       case when fac_name = 'abcd' then 1
 12            when fac_name = 'xyz'  then -1
 13            else 100
 14       end hm
 15     from test
 16    )
 17  select cif, facno, fac_name
 18  from inter
 19  where facno not in (select facno from inter
 20                      where fac_name = 'xyz'
 21                        and cif in (select cif
 22                                    from inter
 23                                    where hm in (-1, 1)
 24                                    group by cif
 25                                    having sum(hm) = 0
 26                                   )
 27                     )
 28  order by cif, facno;

       CIF      FACNO FAC_N
---------- ---------- -----
      1234        234 abcd
      1234        236 ooo
      1244        345 abcd
      1244        346 abcde
      1278        238 xyz

SQL>
```